# Java custom class w/ Defaultlistmodel added elements aren't saved

Tags: java

I have an exercise where the goal is to generate a random list(with a total max price) with presents from another list. I'm not that far yet, at the moment I'm stuck with adding items to the main list(cadeauModel).

I've added multiple 'Cadeau' to the list and Java acknowledges that but when I want to see those items they all say "null ter waarde van 0,00000". So my question is, why doesn't it show(or save?) the items and prices that I added in the main method and how do I fix it.

```
public class Cadeau {

String name;
double price;

public Cadeau(String naam, double prijs) {
    naam = name;
    prijs = price;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("%s ter waarde van %f", name, price);
}



public class CadeauGen extends javax.swing.JFrame {


private DefaultListModel<Cadeau> selectedCadeauModel;
private DefaultListModel cadeauModel;


public CadeauGen() {
    initComponents();

    cadeauModel = new DefaultListModel();
    cadeauModel.addElement(new Cadeau("TV", 250));
    cadeauModel.addElement(new Cadeau("Wollen sokken", 20));
    cadeauModel.addElement(new Cadeau("Goedkope GSM", 79));
    cadeauModel.addElement(new Cadeau("Fles Champagne", 58));
    cadeauModel.addElement(new Cadeau("Cadeaubon", 50));
    cadeauModel.addElement(new Cadeau("Zak spekken", 18));
    cadeauModel.addElement(new Cadeau("Strips", 24));

    System.out.println(cadeauModel);
    lstGeneratedPresents.setModel(cadeauModel);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `println` statements are displaying Java's default (i.e. unset) values for the `String` and `double` types, respectively. This is because you're not actually setting the `name` and `price` instance variables of the `Cadeau` class in the constructor.

This:

```
public Cadeau(String naam, double prijs) {
    naam = name;
    prijs = price;
}
```

...should be:

```
public Cadeau(String naam, double prijs) {
    name = naam;
    price = prijs;
}
```

In your version, you're setting the input parameters to the value of the instance variables (which doesn't make any sense); it should be the other way around.

Comment: Ah bloody hell, wasted 2 hours on this and probably would've wasted much more if you didn't answer this. Thanks for the quick reply.